# In my console calculator(C) scanf work incorrect in tree function in which i input the value of variable

Tags: c, variables, tree, calculator

I am writing a console calculator in C and faced with the following problem. I use tree to save and input value of variables. I need to enter the value of a separate variable, but when using the scanf function, the value of the next entered element is entered into this variable.(sorry for my English I am not a native speaker) For example: a+2 will output 2.

```
/* structure for tree */
typedef struct tree_of_variables 
{
    char name[7];
    double value;
    struct tree_of_variables* left;
    struct tree_of_variables* right;
} tree; 

/* function to save and input variables using tree */
double tree_check(tree** t, char* c) 
{
    int j = 0;
    double b;
    if (*t == NULL)
    {
        tree* t_helper = (tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        memcpy(t_helper->name, c, 7);
        t_helper->left = NULL;
        t_helper->right = NULL;
        printf("Input value ");
        while (c[j] >= 'a' && c[j] <= 'z' && j != 7)
            printf("%c", c[j++]);
        printf(":\n");
        scanf("%lf", &b);
        t_helper->value = b;
        *t = t_helper;
        return (*t)->value; 
    }

/* part of code from main */

/* char c, int i, char perem[7], tree *tr = NULL, double d) */
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
{
    i = 0;
    while (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        perem[i] = c;
        i++;
        if (i > 6)
        {
            printf("ERROR! Invalid variable\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        c = getchar();
    }
perem[i] = '\0';
d = tree_check(&tr, perem);
printf("Variable: %lf", d) /* output 0 */
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about an input problem, not a tree-building problem.  But it looks like your input code is (a) sprinkled around and (b) intermixed with the tree-building code -- that is, there's input code buried down in `tree_check`.  But sprinkling the code around like that makes it hard to see, and hard to follow, and hard to debug, and hard to ask about here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I recommend you write the input code all by itself, and debug it all by itself.  Don't even worry about building tree nodes yet — just make sure the input works properly.  I see calls to `scanf`, and calls to `getchar`, but that's a sure sign of trouble, as those two don't play well together.  If you're doing anything fancy, usually the easiest way is not to use either of those, but to read whole lines (as strings) using `fgets`, and then parse them some other way (maybe `sscanf`, or `atof`, or `strtod`).

Comment: Yes, the problem is in input. Scanf just take the value of the next element inputed in console. But i want to input value by myself